# Signal-Slot makes a mess

Tags: c++, qt, logic

I am trying to create a image-saving application using Qt. Now the stub

```
class ImageSaver:public QObject
{
    int index;
    QWebPage * main_Page;
    QNetworkAccessManager * manager;
    QNetworkReply * reply;
    QString file_Name;
    QSet<QString> image_Addresses;
    QString web_Address;
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void image_Saved();
public slots:
    void request_Image();
    void on_Finished(bool status);
    void got_Reply(QNetworkReply * reply);
public:
    ImageSaver();
    void start();
};

ImageSaver::ImageSaver()
{
    index = 0;

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

    reply = NULL;

    connect(main_Page,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(on_Finished(bool)));

    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(got_Reply(QNetworkReply*)));

    connect(this,SIGNAL(image_Saved()),this,SLOT(request_Image()));
}

void ImageSaver::start()
{
    //loads the url 
    // In the end of the loading it will emit load_Finished(bool)
    // So that signal will execute on_Finished(bool)
}

void ImageSaver::request_Image()
{
    QString temp_Address = *(image_Addresses.begin()+index);

   //makes a request to the server to give the image "temp_Address"
   //When the server gives the reply signal finished(QNetworkReply*) will be emitted
   // this in turn will call the got_Reply(QNetworkReply*)
}

void ImageSaver::on_Finished(bool status)
{
       //collects all the images's url addresses, and pushes them in the list 
        //"image_Addresses"
        //Then emits image_Saved();
        //This signal will wake up the function request_Image()
}

void ImageSaver::got_Reply(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    //Image is extracted from the reply and got saved in the same name as in the page
    //index got increased;
    //emits the signal image_Saved();
    //This signal will activate the function request_Image()
}

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);
    ImageSaver a;
    a.start();
    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

In short First call is to "start".That calls "on_Finished" and there is no problem untill this. So all the image files's addresses got pushed in the list. Next is one by one request for image[i] made, and the reply image got saved. This thing is happening repeatedly. Here only I am getting problem. Crashes are appearing in this operation especially in saving the image.

My assumption is "signal-slot" is not like function call, thy are more or less like thread but operates on the same function( pointer). So when one signal requests for painter, which is already rendering something then the crash will appear.

Can anybody say the fact behind the crash and how to save all the images without crash?

**EDIT:**
      Hi, This is the full code. Run this one, and click the message boxes contineously

```
    #include <QApplication>
#include <QDir>
#include <QImage>
#include <QObject>
#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QSet>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkReply>
#include <QtNetwork/QNetworkRequest>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebElement>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebFrame>
#include <QtWebKit/QWebPage>
#include <QUrl>

class ImageSaver:public QObject
{
    int index;
    QWebPage * main_Page;
    QNetworkAccessManager * manager;
    QNetworkReply * reply;
    QString file_Name;
    QSet<QString> image_Addresses;
    QString web_Address;
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void image_Saved();
public slots:
    void request_Image();
    void on_Finished(bool status);
    void got_Reply(QNetworkReply * reply);
public:
    ImageSaver();
    void start();
protected:
    //void show_Frame(QWebFrame * frame);
};

ImageSaver::ImageSaver()
{
    index = 0;

    this->main_Page = new QWebPage;

    manager = new QNetworkAccessManager;

    reply = NULL;

    connect(main_Page,SIGNAL(loadFinished(bool)),this,SLOT(on_Finished(bool)));

    connect(manager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),this,SLOT(got_Reply(QNetworkReply*)));

    connect(this,SIGNAL(image_Saved()),this,SLOT(request_Image()));
}

void ImageSaver::start()
{
    web_Address = "yahoo.com";

    QDir dir;

    dir.mkdir(web_Address);

    QUrl url = QUrl::fromUserInput(web_Address);

    main_Page->mainFrame()->load(url);
}

void ImageSaver::request_Image()
{
    QString temp_Address = *(image_Addresses.begin()+index);

        int a = temp_Address.lastIndexOf("/");
        file_Name = temp_Address.mid(a+1);

        //Without the below message box, the program closes shortly
        //This message box is slowing down that effect
        QMessageBox hh;
        hh.setText(file_Name);
        hh.exec();
        QNetworkRequest request= QNetworkRequest(QUrl(temp_Address));
        request.setRawHeader("img","src");
        manager->get(request);
}

void ImageSaver::on_Finished(bool status)
{
    if(status)
    {
        QMessageBox mm;
        mm.setText("Finished");
        mm.exec();

        QWebElementCollection temp_Collection= main_Page->mainFrame()->findAllElements("*");

        for(int i=0;i<temp_Collection.count();++i)
        {
            QWebElement temp_Element = temp_Collection[i];
            if(temp_Element.tagName().contains("img",Qt::CaseInsensitive) && temp_Element.attributeNames().contains("src",Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                QString image_Web_Address = temp_Element.attribute("src");
                if(!image_Addresses.contains(image_Web_Address))
                    image_Addresses.insert(image_Web_Address);
            }
        }
        emit image_Saved();
        QMessageBox kk;
        kk.setText("Image is going to be saved");
        kk.exec();
    }

    else
    {
        QMessageBox mm;
        mm.setText("Not ready");
        mm.exec();
    }

    QMessageBox mm;
    mm.setText("Getting out of finished");
    mm.exec();
}

void ImageSaver::got_Reply(QNetworkReply * reply)
{
    QImage image;
    if(image.load(static_cast<QIODevice *>(reply),0))
        image.save(web_Address+QDir::separator()+file_Name,0);

    ++index;
    emit image_Saved();
}

/*
void ImageSaver::show_Frame(QWebFrame * temp_Frame)
{
    QImage image(temp_Frame->contentsSize(),QImage::Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied);
    image.fill(Qt::transparent);

    QPainter painter(&image);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing,true);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::TextAntialiasing,true);
    painter.setRenderHint(QPainter::SmoothPixmapTransform,true);

    temp_Frame->documentElement().render(&painter);

    painter.end();

    foreach(QWebFrame * temp_Frame0,temp_Frame->childFrames())
        show_Frame(temp_Frame0);
}
*/

int main(int argc,char * argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc,argv);

    ImageSaver a;
    a.start();

    return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

This is the pro file

```
QT += webkit network

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp
```

Comment: Where is it crashing? Is there a message?  You should provide a *complete* and minimal example to demonstrate the behavior.  The slot is like a function call, the signal is just a way to call the slot later (during the event loop).  It is not obvious why you would split the algorithm up into multiple slots.  I would try and put this whole process into one slot and see if you still crash.

Comment: Judging by your current example, you're using the default method for connecting signals and slots.  This is a DIRECT Connection, meaning you're essentially just making a function call.  There's no multi-threading going on here unless you're doing some threading somewhere we can't see it.  Tom K references a "Queued Connection", but it doesn't look like that's what you're doing.
See this: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/threads-qobject.html#signals-and-slots-across-threads

Comment: If it crashes, provide a backtrace. Your assumption about signal/slots is wrong, they are normal method calls, no multi-threading involved.

Comment: @Tom Try the code in the edit. And if you say how to put the whole process into one slot, I will be very thankful to you.

Comment: @Frank They don't seem like normal method calls. In normal method calls, the calling function waits for the return but in signal-slot it will continue with the code after emitting a signal

Comment: @ prabhakaran, whether code continue execution after emoting signal, or "wait for return" depend on connection type. Anyway, signals & slots mechanism very close to normal function calls in behaviour

Comment: @prabhakaran When using DirectConnection, which is the default connection type unless the involved QObjects live in different threads, emitting a signal blocks until the connected slots were executed. What you describe would be a QueuedConnection, which must be passed explicitly when connecting. As you don't pass it, and don't seem to use multithreading, your connections are direct and emitting a signal is just a matter of function call(s) with an additional level of indirection.

Comment: @Frank You can see a function "request_Image" in the given code, in that you can find a message box "hh". Just remove this message box, and run the code. If your argument is correct, then all the images should be saved. But, the application won't work in that way. You can check this.

Comment: prabhakaran: Your example proves my point. Running your code, the first "hh" messagebox containing the image filename is shown before the "Image is going to be saved" one, where the order would be different if the emit returned immediately, before the slot is executed. Read the signal/slots docs: "When a signal is emitted, the slots connected to it are usually executed immediately, just like a normal function call. [...]. Execution of the code following the emit statement will occur once all slots have returned". http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/signalsandslots.html

Comment: ...and if you don't believe the Qt documentation, just read Qt code or step into the emit it with a debugger.

Comment: @Frank Try with  different timings on clicking those message boxes. Here, I am getting occasional crash for the code without the message box "hh".

Comment: @Frank Don't click the message box with the message "Image is going to be saved". Wait for some time when it got appeared, then the application will crash.

Comment: I think the reason for your crashes is below. However, using msgboxes to debug code like this is dangerous: If there is a network operation pending and you open a message box, the msgbox will open a local event loop inside exec. If the network op returns while the dialog is open, the called slot will change the app's state. Once you close the dialog, the code after the exec() will be executed, and any assumption that could be made before the exec() isn't valid anymore, due to the slot called by the network op in between. Better don't use blocking exec() calls in such a context at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code crashes because you read beyond the boundaries of the image_Addresses set.

```
void ImageSaver::request_Image()
{
    QString temp_Address = *(image_Addresses.begin()+index);
    ...
```

You increment index after every image received, but there isn't any check anywhere in the code whether index is still less than image_Addresses.size(), so it crashes once dereferencing image_Addresses.begin()+index for index == image_Addresses.size().

Comment: Bull's eye. Now I got rid of those crashes. But, the problem is not all the images got saved.

Answer (score 1):

There may be many solutions to this problem. I think that you should have a look at [The State Machine Framework](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/statemachine-api.html). In easy situations you can just use boolean variable to check if you can go on. You should also think what to do when you're busy processing the image. You can queue request or just reject them. Also you can implement threading, so that new requests are served by new threads.

P.S. Signals are more like events than threads to me.

Answer (score 1):

What's the error and why do you have a `#include` at the end?

FYI there is a `QImage` class you can use instead which includes saving and loading from a `QIODevice*` such as `QNetworkReply` for example. It's extremely rare to need to reinvent the wheel in the massive framework that is Qt.

Comment: The #include "main.moc" is standard practice for when you have signals/slots in your main cpp file.

Comment: It was more about where it is than what it is.

Comment: @AJG85 I think I used that QImage class, see the EDIT.

Comment: I meant you could do something akin to `class ImageSaver : public QImage` and then use containment for the extra bits you want in your version and override anything that you want a bit differently.